# How can I launch parallel tasks in Julia that terminate when one task finds an answer?

Tags: julia

I have a function f(), that runs either returns a matrix, or returns nothing.
I want to take advantage of distributed computing to gain some speed in getting a single matrix.
I only require a single matrix and would like to return that matrix as soon as a task finds it or return nothing if all tasks fail.

I tried the following code, but it is far too slow.

```
@everywhere function f()
    # ... code to construct the matrix ...
   if requirements_met
       return matrix
   else
      return nothing
   end
end

function parallel_sampling(num_attempts::Int)
    result_channel = Remote(()->Channel{Any}(num_attempts)
    @distributed for _ in 1:num_attempts
        put!(result_channel, f())
    end
    for _ in 1:num_attempts
        res = take!(result_channel)
        if !isnothing(res)
            return res
        end
    end
end

function sequential_sampling(num_attempts::Int)
    for _ in 1:num_attempts
        res = f()
        if !isnothing(res)
            return res
        end
    end
end
```

The function sequential sampling is x1000 times faster than the parallel one. I'm not sure if this is because the function f() is already fast that the data transfer to the result channel.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to make the code much faster by simply using @spawnat and not using a remote channel.

```
function parallel_sampling(num_attempts::Int)
    for i in 1:num_attempts
        j = i % nworkers() + 1
        res = @spawnat j f()
        if !isnothing(fetch(res))
            return fetch(res)
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: You'd better use `@spawn` instead of `@spawnat`

Comment: Well, and it seems you does not terminate other tasks after answer found